# Where can I find information about metadata request which my Cosmos DB client makes?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I use Cosmos DB (Core (SQL)) in my Azure Function run in ASP.NET Core 3.1. I have SDK Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.28.0 with CosmosClient in my application with default connection mode (Direct). Despite that all data is send thru TCP I can see HTTP request for some metadata which my CosmosClient does and uses.

I want to know more information about this request? When, why and how often they are made and if I can change them?

Comment: The Cosmos client makes https requests to the gateway to obtain paritition key range and address information so it knows where to send requests to the backend physical partitions via tcp. The client will continue to make these requests during the lifetime of the client instance to obtain updates to pk information, checking every 60 seconds if there are any changes. There is nothing users can configure with these requests. They will not impact the performance of your applications.

Comment: thank you, if you have any source of this information please share it

Comment: We don't typically document this sort of thing as it's largely implementation details and not really something you can do anything about. There are good details on .NET and Java SDK at this link here, both best practices and troubleshooting articles are helpful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/best-practice-dotnet